# Update database schema to allow multiple users

Tags: database, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6, schema

I'm working on an ASP.net Web API application and would like to allow multiple users to have access to their own data without changing the database schema too much.

My tables look a little like this:

```
  public class Asset
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            [Required]
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string AssetTag { get; set; }
            public string Serial { get; set; }
            public int Model { get; set; }
    }

  public class Organisation
    {
        [Required]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int DefaultLocation { get; set; }
        public location Location { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string Contact { get; set; }

}

 public class AssetModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public int ManufacturerId { get; set; }
        public string ModelNumber { get; set; }
}
```

*fields omitted for brevity

Each user should be able to create their own assets / organisations / etc, but should not have access to any other users fields.

I'm yet to add authorization / authentication however I'm probably going to use token based auth as outlined here: 
http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/09/angularjs-token-authentication-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/

Should this be as easy as tacking each users GUID onto each column and applying some logic? Or will I need to completely re-design the database?

Comment: Adding information to the entities about to whom it belongs is fine, let it be just a string or `User` entity (if you need additional information regarding user).